# Why does this simple JNI object construction cause a VM abort and SIGSEGV?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Class:

```
package com.example.foo;

public class Dummy
{
    int value;

    public Dummy(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }   
}
```

JNI snippet:

```
jclass class = (*jni_env)->FindClass(jni_env, "com/example/foo/Dummy");
jmethodID constructor = (*jni_env)->GetMethodID(jni_env, class, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject object = (*jni_env)->NewObject(jni_env, constructor, 0);
```

LogCat output:

```
09-03 11:02:02.937: W/dalvikvm(2179): Invalid indirect reference 0x44e9cf80 in decodeIndirectRef
09-03 11:02:02.937: E/dalvikvm(2179): VM aborting
09-03 11:02:02.937: A/libc(2179): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2179
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewObject()` expects the class object pointer as the second parameter. The constructor method ID is the third parameter. Reformulate like this:

```
jobject object = (*jni_env)->NewObject(jni_env, class, constructor, 17);
```

Where 17 is the argument to the constructor.

Comment: What does this `17` mean here?

Comment: The same thing zero is in the OP's `NewObject()` line - an arbitrary integer argument to the constructor.